# Is there UI-independent Point struct in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, struct

I know several `Point` structs in .NET: `System.Drawing.Point`, `System.Windows.Point`, `Sys.UI.Point`, but all of them are in high-level UI libraries (GDI+, WPF, AJAX). I need a `Point` struct for calculations in my class library which I don't want to tie to any specific UI technology. Is there any UI-independent `Point` struct in .NET? Or I will need to create it myself? That is simple, I know, but sounds like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Agreed. I am looking for this too, for the same reasons.

Comment: I would almost always vote against using `Tuple` if the type has some meaning or broader purpose than a quick one-shot return of multiple items from a method somewhere. `Tuple` has no meaning on its own.

Comment: In .NET classes are usually defined where they are needed, as demonstrated where you found them. I can't think of any implementation elsewhere in the BCL that could use a `Point` class or struct with an `X` and `Y` property, and apparently the .NET team couldn't either.

Comment: Are you working with Spatial data ? You can use Spatial data types, or create a Point class similar to SharpMap's Point class

Comment: What solution did you end up with?

Comment: @tofutim reinvented the wheel :)

Comment: Lol. I'm trying to do PCL cross-platform stuff - ended up using the Splat library.

Comment: @AlekseyShubin So you defined the structure your-self? And what about converting it to PointF or something like that later? I have a Custom.RectangleF structure and MonoTouch use Drawing.RectangleF for positioning. Currently I convert it each time and I don't like this. Trying to see if there is any other way.

Comment: @AlekseyShubin you should accept the most useful advice below as the answer so that your post doesn't remain flagged as unanswered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reinvent the wheel. It will run smoother! Really, if it's just a tiny struct why depend on big assemblies, pulling in a lot of other stuff? Especially on constraint devices like phones... But pay attention on how to use classes and struct correctly if you want best performance.

This is a pretty good read and I *sense* that you want to read it dearly: [Frank Savage on CLR performance](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6082).

Answer (score 19):

To the best of my knowledge there isn't, but as you stated it isn't something hard to implement yourself so I suggest you do that.

You may be tempted to use `Tuple` class as others suggested. While it *can* do the job it isn't something you'll want to reuse over and over. Furthermore you may run into comparison issues, depending on your app specifics.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for that purpose.

Comment: Note that this is a class, not a struct, and is immutable, not mutable.  Using a `Tuple` also removes all information about the type; you no longer have a sensible name for the type, or it's properties.

Comment: @Servy, indeed it is an immutable class as opposed to being a struct, which is a good thing in most cases (I did performance benchmarking a while back). It is not true that it looses type information, because it is a generic class.

Comment: It will depend on the specific context for whether it's better to be a class or struct, however there's a reason most `Point` classes you find are structs.  The typical uses cases for them *tend* to benefit from being structs, not that it'll be true in all cases, though the difference is still important.  As for losing the type information, you most certainly do.  When I see a `Tuple<int, int>` I don't know that it represents a point in a coordinate system.  When I see a `Point` class, I do.  For the `Tuple` I can't see which property represents which dimension, I just need to know it, etc.

Comment: @Servy is right. Properties for a Tuple class is named Item1, Item2, ItemN (...). Not exactly as clear as Point.X/Y or Coordinate.Latitude/Longitude/Altitude.

Comment: @Crono1981, I get it now! Indeed, that is true.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `System.Drawing.Point` or `System.Drawing.PointF` anyway. True, it can be converted to and from the appropriate GDI+ structure, but in itself, it's simply a .NET structure. It's pure managed struct, that just happens to be COM visible and convertible :)

Comment: Are you saying that the GDI ones would be a better pick than the other UI-based ones?

Comment: @StevenDoggart The way I see it, `System.Drawing` is pretty much always there, even in Mono, so why not use it? It doesn't automatically require you to use GDI+ or anything. And it's a decent base-line "standard" Point.

Comment: Let's assume I (or someone else) will want to create WPF application that uses a function from my library which have a point type parameter. Than I will have to convert WPF `Point`'s to GDI+ `Point`'s, and that seems to be very unnatural for me, as there are no other usages of GDI+ - neither in UI, nor in my library. It seems to be more logical to convert to `Point` specific for my library.

Comment: @AlekseyShubin Yes, but you'll have to do the conversion with your type anyway, whether you use WPF's `Point` or GDI+'s `PointF`. And we're talking about a structure with two simple fields, does it really matter all that much?

Comment: @Luaan it would matter if the type was meant to also be used in a non-UI application layer such as a service or in business rules.

Comment: @Crono1981 True, but that's pretty much the consideration here - does it bother you you have to carry `System.Drawing` around? There isn't anything smaller in the BCL, so if you do care, write your own.

Comment: @Luaan I totally see your point, but I still think it's a mistake to force dependency on this assembly if there's no more significant reason to. Remember that System.Drawing **isn't supported by portable class library projects**. So if it ever becomes necessary to deploy the assembly on multiple platforms, this dependency would become a problem. As long a shot it is, it would be sufficient for me to consider making my own struct.

Comment: @Crono1981 Yes, that's a very good point. In any case, this is going to present some usability issues. Ideally, you'd want your Point to be easily convertible to either the GDI+ or the WPF version - but you can't do that without referencing **both** `System.Drawing.Point` and `System.Windows.Point`. But yeah, it's probably best to just create your own struct. The conversion is very simple and anyone can make an extension method to ease the use if they want.

Comment: @Luaan you are right that if this structure is meant to be used as UI drawing coordinates then conversion will be necessary at one point. However this conversion logic could (and *should*) reside in a UI assembly and remains unknown to the assembly holding the structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create your own `Point` class, you could consider using the `Tuple` class [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You could pass along a pair of coordinates of whatever type you want to your class library instead of forcing a user to instantiate a new class.

If you want to provide several helper methods to the consumer of your library, however, I would create your own class.  Tuples are great for quick ways to pass around data.

Comment: Yes, I definitely will prefer to create my own Point instead of using Tuple, if there is no other solution.