# Customized Type Point Structure in C#

Tags: c#, struct, types, point

I am trying to do some two dimensional plotting in C#. I found that the types of X and Y coordinate data in System.Drawing.Point are int, and they are float System.Drawing.PointF. I am wondering that is there any appropriate point structure with customized type like `Point<uint>` or `Point<long>` which also include built-in functions `Add`, `Equals`, `Offset`, and etc.

```
Point<uint> Point1;
Point1.X = 4200000000;  //  Type of X is uint
Point1.Y = 4200000000;  //  Type of Y is uint
```

I know that there is another way to use `Tuple<uint, uint>`

```
Tuple<uint, uint> Point1 = new Tuple<uint, uint>(4200000000, 4200000000);
```

However, Tuple item is readonly and it is lack of variety of built-in functions.

Comment: It sounds like something you could pretty easily write yourself. What's holding you back?

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531084/is-there-ui-independent-point-struct-in-net

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thank you for your comments. Considering about portability and readability, I prefer to use existed library than write my own struct.

Comment: There is no `uint` or `long` point structure in the base class libraries of the .net framework. however it will be easy enough to make one https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Point.cs

Comment: Point are pixel count on monitors or images) and the size is limited to the max number of pixels on a monitor so an int is sufficient.  The default number type in c# is an int and you have to cast to other types when needed.  Using an uint doubles the max positive number and monitors and images usually do not need the larger positive size.